Number of ways to arrange characters in the alphabet
Given an alphabet of size A and a bowl of alphabet soup of size S. Assuming that the distribution of characters in any one bowl is uniform, what is the likelihood that a random bowl contains at least one complete alphabet?

Since the order of the characters in the soup is not important there are $N={{(S+A-1)!}\over{(S-1)!A!}}$ unique bowls of soup.
However not every one of the N solutions are equally likely. There are $R=A^S$ possible soups of which each is equally likely and some are duplicate.
The probability that a random bowl of soup contains at least one complete alphabet should be $p={Q \over R}$ where $Q$ is the total number of equally likely soups that contain the complete alphabet ().
I have brute forced the first few solutions for A=3



$S$
$Q \over R$
$T \over N$




3
$6 \over 27$
$1 \over 10$


4
$36 \over 81$
$3 \over 15$


5
$150 \over 243$
$6 \over 21$


6
$540 \over 729$
$10 \over 28$


7
$1806 \over 2187$
$15 \over 36$


8
$5796 \over 6561$
$21 \over 45$


9
$18150 \over 19683$
$28 \over 55$


10
$55980 \over 59049$
$36 \over 66$


11
$171006 \over 177147$
$45 \over 78$


12
$519156 \over 531441$
$55 \over 91$


13
$1569750 \over 1594323$
$66 \over 105$


14
$4733820 \over 4782969$
$78 \over 120$



I am unable to find a generic formula for Q. Please provide a rational for how to come up with it.

What have you tried so far? Can you solve this for small cases like a three letter alphabet and a four letter soup?

What do you mean by "normal"?  Do you mean "uniform"?

Yes. Uniform. I've updated it. Thanks

Question 2 is actually a Stars and Bars question.  For Stars and Bars theory, see this article and this article.  The wrinkle is that the lower bound on the variables is $~+1,~$ rather than $~0.~$  This is easily accommodated through the change of variables $~y_i = x_i - 1.$

$T$ is the number of the natural solutions of the equation $x_1+\cdots+x_A=S$, where $x_i$ is the number of $i$th character in the soup, given by $$T=\binom{S-1}{A-1}={{(S-1)!}\over{(A-1)!(S-A)!}}.$$
The probability is given by $p=\color{red}{\frac{T}{N}}$ only if we assume $N=\binom{S+A-1}{A-1}$ cases are equally likely, which is not realistic as the experiment is typically that $S$ times a character is randomly chosen and added to the soup. In this case, the correct probability is computed as
$$p=\color{blue}{\sum_{n_1,\dots,n_A\ge1}\binom{S}{n_1,\dots,n_A} \prod_{i=1}^A \left (\frac{1}{A}\right)^{n_i}=\frac{A!S(S,A)}{A^S}}$$
where $S(n,r)$ denotes the Stirling number of the second kind.

Why the outcomes of the experiment after ignoring the appearance order of the characters in the generation phase are not equally likely?
Let $S=3, A=3.$ Then, the probabilities of having soups with configurations $x_1=2,x_2=0,x_3=1$ and $x_1=1,x_2=1,x_3=1$ are $\frac{3!}{2!0!1!}\left (\frac{1}{3}\right)^{3}$ (112,121,211) and $3!\left (\frac{1}{3}\right)^{3}$ (123,132,213,213,312,321), respectively.

See here on how the number of the positive and non-negative integral solutions of the equation $x_1+\cdots+x_A=S$ can be obtained.

If the individual characters in the soup are equally likely (uniform distribution) then aren't all possible combinations also equally likely? Like when a sequence of bits are chosen at random all possible resulting values are equally likely. In that case $A^S$ because order matters...

Can you elaborate slightly on how you arrive at $T$ please? What is $x_A$?

@Maximilian just added some more details.
